# How can I find object with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7

Thats my code, I was changing, fixing, trying another modules, but still can not get a respond with my div text extracted.

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get('http://www.helloworld.com/')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('main')

WebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='main']"));
webElement.getText();
```

I was trying with bs4 package but there is a big problem, becouse the data what i want is possible to get only when i am loged in on the website, and in bs4 respond was like from guest account, without login in.

Here is a Traceback what i got usint that code with Selenium:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python27/get text value div.py", line 8, in <module>
    WebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='main']"));
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'
```

Aftter a small fix, I am using this:

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get('http://www.helloworld.com/')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('main')
main_text = element.text
```

The respond after `print element.text` in shell is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    element.text
  File "D:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 50, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "D:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 228, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 152, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: u'\'[JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file: "file:///c:/dokume~1/tomek/lokale%20einstellungen/temp/tmpupvgr2/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js" line: 7623}]\' when calling method: [nsICommandProcessor::execute]'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where did you get the following from? Looks like Java to me.

```
 WebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='main']"));

webElement.getText();
```

Try:

```python
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get('http://www.helloworld.com/')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('main')
print element.text #There's no text under div main, what would you expect?

footer = driver.find_element_by_id('footer')
print footer.text
# Should print out "Copyright ©2013 helloworld.com. All Rights Reserved. About Us   |  Privacy Policy "
```

Comment: Well, looks like it works but why when i use command `main_text` in Shell then the respond is always `u''` ? it's not the text from div. Any idea where i am doing wrong?

Comment: what's the result of `print element.text` from shell?

Comment: @Mezulith: Because there's no text in `div main`. What's your expected text?

Comment: Becouse it was only example site, the real site is http://game6.margonem.pl This is game in browser and after when you log in there is a div with text, that text is a cord on square map, I need that to create my own bot. I am new in python but i want to realize that project for my own knowledge. Sadly the result of 'print element.text' is the same, I am stack like 10 hours with trying to get cord from the square map using a div to get that. I used example site and example div just in care.

Comment: What happens if you print `driver.page_source`? after you have logged in? Is this the page you expect to be on?

Comment: @aychedee after print `driver.page_source` there is coming source code from the site, after using find option i found a part what i am interested: `/></div><div id="botloc" tip="Werbin">31,24</div>` The numbers **31,24** are cords or a square map of my current possition.

Comment: @aychedee: Should i use another code to get text from div inside the another div? or it doesnt matter how deep is div what i am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If the information you want is inside a div with an id of `botloc` then you need to grab that element.

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.get('http://www.helloworld.com/')
bot_location = driver.find_element_by_id('botloc').text
print bot_location
```

Comment: You are the best! The answer comes from master who let me go ahead instead of stuck 2 days with that, i thank you soooo muuuch!!

Comment: In my next step i am trying to loop the bot_location to refresh it every single second. I contructed: `import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://game6.margonem.pl//')
botloc = driver.find_element_by_id('botloc').text
print botloc

def repeat():
    while 1 == 1:
        botloc = driver.find_element_by_id('botloc').text
        print botloc
` But the respond after typing repeat in Shell is: `<function repeat at 0x015BBFB0>` any idea to fix?

Comment: Did you just downvote and unaccept my answer and then ask a second question in the comments? Wow. You will need to call `repeat()`. And you should probably pass the driver into the function as well.